# On OnePlus One w CyanogenMod, how do I add notes to a Google Contact?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.1-lollipop, oneplus-one

On oneplus one cyanogenmod 12.1 w Android 5.1.1 Lollipop, how do I add notes to a google contact? When I go to Edit the Google Contact, there is no Notes section and there is no button to add that section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On CyanogenMod, the notes section is after the building icon with the dialog box. See picture attached. If you don't have any notes yet, the field doesn't have a blank so doesn't appear editable.

[image]
[image]